# C# Outlook 2016 Application ActiveInspector is null

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

I create a c# Console Application that connects to Outlook in order to select an especific ribbon to execute a specific control. The problem is the ActiveInspector() method returns null!

Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;

        Redemption.SafeInspector sInspector = new Redemption.SafeInspector();
        sInspector.Item = app.ActiveInspector();//this returns null!!
    }
```

Comment: Is there an inspector actually shown? Or just an explorer?

Comment: ActiveExplorer() and ActiveWindow()

Comment: So there is no active inspector, right?

Comment: yes, its null. Can i access to ribbon in other way?

Comment: yes, when an inspector opens. If there is no inspector, there is nothing to access. What exactly are you trying to do and why?

Comment: i am trying to access to a ribbon of an addin, because i need to execute a button on that ribbon.  I Create a console application to do that, and app object as ActiveExplorer(), ActiveWindow() but ActiveInspector() is null... I don´t know what. even when accessing app.Inspectors (array count is 0). In version <= 2007 i use app.Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar and it works.

Comment: Wait a sec, why are you using ActiveInspector and SafeInspector? You need ActiveExplorer and SafeExplorer.

Comment: With SafeExplorer i can access to ribbon ?

Comment: Of course. Use SafeExplorer.Riibbon. See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm

Comment: Cool! It Works! Thanks